# Excel custom function | formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I'd like to get the SUM of cells with a specific format in the same format.

For example, I have a column of column of cells with:

```
23/02/11
00/01/02
05/12/06

28/15/19 < I want the total to be displayed like so.
```

Is this possbile, or should I split each amount into different cells? Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Those entries are likely to be interpreted as dates.  Even if you change the delimiter, you would need convoluted formulas to do what you want.  The simple solution would be to have the numbers in separate cells.  BTW, what happens if any sum exceeds two digits?

Comment: I agree with fixer1234 but this can be done quite easily with vba but not sure if you want that?

Comment: Thanks Fixer. It's not important that the sums be two digit. I'll do what you suggest and split each entry into their own cell.

Comment: So is this question still valid? Or do you have your solution?

Comment: Actually you could use len and left to achieve this!  With a string concat....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT and LEFT or MID to find the values and sum:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--LEFT($A$1:$A$3,FIND("/",$A$1:$A$3)-1))&"/"&SUMPRODUCT(--MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$3,"/",REPT(" ",99)),99,99))&"/"&SUMPRODUCT(--MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$3,"/",REPT(" ",99)),198,99))
```

The substitute is splitting the three numbers by 99 spaces so we can estimate where the split is.  The `--` turns those text strings into number that the SUMPRODUCT adds as it iterates.

[image]